# Book about Lattices, Boolean algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, reference-works

I have a subject about Applied Algebra and the first part of it it's about lattices, distributive lattices, hasse diagram, etc..
Next day we are going to start with Boolean Algebra. My professor is following the book:

> Lidl Rudolf; Applied abstract algebra (2nd edition)

But I want to train and the book has very little exercises and shows no solutions. Can someone recomend me a book or document (not an advanced book) with solved exercises
about this stuff? Thanks